# awk script along with for loop

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have a data set `t.txt`:

```
827 819
830 826
828 752
752 694
828 728
821 701
724 708
826 842
719 713
764 783
812 820
829 696
697 849
840 803
752 774
```

I also have a second file `t1.txt`:

```
752
728
856
693
713
792
812
706
737
751
745
```

I am trying to extract corresponding column 2 elements of the second file sequentially from the data set.

I have used: `awk -F " " '$1==752 {print $2}' t.txt >> t2.txt`

How can i use for loop for the above instruction and populate it in one text file instead of doing it one by one?

output for 752 will be 694. This 694 should be written in a different text file. For 812, it should give me 820. Both 694 and 820 should be written in the same text file. It should parse till end of the input file.

I was trying :

```
for i in `cat t1.txt` | awk -F " "  '$1==$i {print $2}' t.txt >> t2.txt
```

which is throwing syntax error.

Comment: Please show your desired output.  For example, when the second file contains 856, what do you want printed?

Comment: For the line in `t1.txt` that reads 856, what do you want printed?  856 does not appear in `t.txt`.  For the line reading 728, what do you want printed?  728 does appear in `t.txt` but only in column 2 and your other examples were for matching in column 1.  _Better yet, just show the complete output that you want from the given sample input._

Comment: The input file has got 1650 lines. However, for situations like 856 the iteration can continue to the next line of t1.txt and do nothing about 856.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer for 3rd Version of This Question

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next;} $1 in a {print $2;}' t1.txt t.txt
694
820
774
```

#### Answer for 2nd Version of This Question

For every line in `t1.txt`, this checks to see if the same number appears in either column 1 of `t.txt`.  If it does, the number in column 2 of the same line is printed:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a {print a[$1]}' t.txt t1.txt
694
820
```

To save the output in file `t2.txt`, use:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a {print a[$1]}' t.txt >t2.txt
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  This reads through `t.txt` and creates an array `a` of its values.
- `$1 in a {print a[$1]}`

  For each number in file `t1.txt`, this checks to see if the number appears in array `a` and, if so, prints out the corresponding value.

Comment: Your script is getting me values of column 1 as well. I require only column 2 values. If a number from t1.txt is in column 2. It can be omitted and proceed to the next number in t1.txt.

Comment: Desired output will only be : 694 and 820

Comment: John1024 I have changed the input file. The out put obtained is : 774 820 while the desire output is : 694 774 820 because there are 2 instances of 752

Comment: John1024 thanks for the previous reply.  Could it be tweaked to take care of multiple instances?

Comment: Could be tweaked to `awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = a[$1] $2 ORS } $1 in a { printf("%s", a[$1]) }' t.txt t1.txt`. The general principle is sound.

Comment: My desired out put would be : 694 820 774. I am not getting this